# How can I restrict a user's access to just a single node of an AEM website?

Tags: aem

I'd like to restrict a user's access to just a specific node within an AEM website.  I want them to be able to manage a blog; they should be able to view the blog (of course), add/edit/delete entries/comments, upload photos, add/remove other collaborators, etc.  However, I don't want them to have access to or even see anything else within AEM.

I have tried giving access to just the blog node under the content path (`/content/geometrixx/en/blog`), but when I try to log into AEM as this user and edit the blog (`localhost:4502/cf#/content/geometrixx/en/blog.html`), I get the following error:

```
No resource found
Cannot serve request to /cf in /libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp
```

I've tried giving write access to the `/content/geometrixx/en/blog` node and read access to everything else, and it seems to work, but of course, the user is able to see way too much.  It would seem there is some particular node that a user must have `read` access to in order to edit content nodes, but I'm not sure what that is.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is the user a member of the 'contributors' group? They need access to paths other than /content in order for the authoring tools to work. Try adding this group to the user if it is missing.

Comment: I'm afraid that would give them too much access, as the `contributors` group is configured to view everything.

Comment: Maybe edit the group and remove /content permissions? CQ needs certain paths to allow the author interface to work - this is why you have a 404 on /cf because it can't load the Content Finder. You also might hit problems viewing the tree but that might be OK if the user had the full URL. You could also try copying the rights from the contributors group into a new group one at a time until it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would go to the /useradmin, chose the user, and in the Permissions tab I would allow access to the below and its child pages:

```
/content/geometrixx/en/blog - allow read modify create delete replicate 
/apps/geometrixx/ - allow read only
/etc/designs/geometrixx - allow read only
/libs - allow read only
/etc/clientlibs - allow read only (optional)
/etc/workflow - allow read only (optional)
```

This is roughly the solution I use in our setup. As you are aware, you need to give at least read-only to the directories where cq components sit, as well as the components from your application, in this case geometrixx.

edit: Also useful to read: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CQ53ACLsMappingToCRX2.html

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly you really need to understand the different pieces of functionality of cq, where they reside (/libs, /apps/, /etc/, etc...) and what is required to have a page properly rendered.

Is it a requirement you have for both author and publisher?
Reading https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.2/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/security/authorization/GlobPattern.html can also help you set ACLs.

I suggest you create a custom group with deny jcr:all on /, and then set the ACL as described by dex and test to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to give the modified access instead of read access,
/content/geometrixx/en/blog - allow read modify

As you need access to single blog node and its jcr:content